# What are CSS vendor prefixes?

Tags: css

I started using Bootstrap. Therefore I started reading [getting started section](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/). Somewhere [near here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/#package-managers) is a note about "autoprefixer". I didn't know what that means. After one click I was [here](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer). And I tryed to understand what "autoprefixer" is. The problem was that the first sentence is this "PostCSS plugin to parse CSS and add vendor prefixes to CSS rules using values from Can I Use. ". Finally, I saw that PostCSS is CSS processor with some magic result and it can use a huge amount of plugins. One of them is "autoprefixer". It adds "vendor prefixes" to CSS rules. But, what are the vendor prefixes?

Comment: Prefixes in css are used in some value for browser support. That mean the value need the bowser prefix to work in that browser. Like ˋdisplay: -ms-grid;´

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Hm, I quite tired and bored from this but the answer is [here](https://www.lifewire.com/css-vendor-prefixes-3466867)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When new features are introduced to the CSS specification, or simply as a test balloon by one browser vendor, the feature is often hidden behind a vendor prefix. E.g. `border-radius` started as `-webkit-border-radius` in Chrome/Webkit browsers, and `-moz-border-radius` in Firefox. If you want to use such a new feature which is not yet standardised across the board but must be prefixed like this, you need to add all the various `-webkit-*` and `-moz-*` forms to your CSS file to support it in all browsers. An autoprefixer makes this easier by allowing you to just use the standard name `border-radius`, and it'll add all the vendor-specific prefixed versions as alternatives automatically.